# Web fonts print with missing characters in Chrome on Windows XP

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webfonts

When printing a web font in Google Chrome on Windows XP, there are missing characters, and the web font appears to be rendering as a system font of some kind, see screenshot:

[image: Web fonts in Google Chrome on Windows XP]

The font is Petersburg, and this is code used to render it:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Petersburg'; 
    src: url('fonts/1DB4EA_0_0.eot');
    src: url('fonts/1DB4EA_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/1DB4EA_0_0.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/1DB4EA_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

It is worth noting I was seeing the issue up until a couple of days on my virtual machine (I'm a Mac user), but the problem mysteriously went away on my end. Unfortunately, my client is still seeing the issue on her Windows machine. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your printer settings change True Type fonts printing from something like "Substitute with device fonts" or "Send as a Softfont" to "Print as image"

Comment: Thanks for the response, which settings are you referring to? Browser settings, or system settings. Having trouble finding it. Thanks!

Comment: I was talking about printer driver settings.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately not having any luck with that. Looks like this may actually be a [Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132239&q=font%20feature=Printing&sort=feature&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary)